# Cambio del mensaje de bienvenida en el chat de "La Tertulia"

Tags: discusión, chat

En el chat principal del sitio, *[La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia)*, se puede leer ahora mismo el siguiente mensaje de bienvenida:

> Lugar de chateo para los grammar punkies de Spanish Language

Se está debatiendo sobre la idoneidad de usar la expresión *grammar punkies* en dicha descripción, dado que puede que los visitantes no entiendan [el concepto](http://grammarpunki.com/elena-alvarez-mellado/) y tiendan a darle una connotación negativa.

Así pues, me gustaría proponer oficialmente un cambio en el mensaje de bienvenida. Se aceptan respuestas como posibles opciones, empezando por la opción propuesta ya en el chat, que yo mismo incluiré. Voten ustedes por la opción que más les guste o añadan una nueva si ninguna lo hace. Tengan en cuenta que el tamaño del mensaje es limitado.

Fecha límite para la votación: viernes 26 de abril.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pasa y chatea, habla, departe, platica, conversa, dialoga... di cosas

Comment: me encanta :___)

Answer (score 1):

## Lugar de chateo para académicos, grammar punkies y demás amantes del idioma español

Comment: buena idea, me gusta.

Answer (score 1):

## Seas Nebrija o Korreas, seas Góngora o Quevedo, habla amigo y entra, aquí a tu lugar de chateo.

Answer (score 1):

## Donde se habla

<sub>NOTA: No me deja poner una respuesta tan corta, así que añado esta nota</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## Lugar de chateo para los grammar punkies de Spanish Language

No cambiar el mensaje. Dejarlo como está.

Answer (score 0):

## Lugar de chateo para enseñantes, estudiantes y amantes del lenguaje español

Answer (score 0):

## Speak amigo and enter

(A play on words from Lord of the Rings' "Speak friend and enter".)

Answer (score 0):

## Lugar de chateo para los grammar junkies de Spanish Language

No entiendo porqué dice "*punkies*" (vándalos, gamberros). Para mi en todo caso debería decir *junkies* (adictos).

Es un simple juego de palabras con el mensaje existente que me planteé poner como un simple comentario en [la entrada que propone no cambiar el mensaje](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3073/5481), pero entonces no se podría votar esta versión.

Creo que más que gamberros la gente que aparece por La Tertulia son *junkies* o [*yonquis*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cCwWojE) de, si no de la lengua española, por lo menos de Spanish.SE.

Comment: Lo de _punkies_ es en contraposición a _grammar nazis_. En la pregunta hay un enlace al blog de Mellado, que es quien nos descubrió el concepto.